# Flutter Transform.rotate How to make it work when press the button , not automatically

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have widget I want to move when I press the button. But when I add Transform.rotate or Transform.scale and when I add a button inside it disappears widget ,
 how can I make it work manually when I press

```
AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: _controller,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              DragObject(image: 'image/w1.png',position: post1,dataName: 't1',dataColor: Colors.blue,textField:null),

            ],
          ),
            builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child){
              return Transform.translate(
      offset: Offset.zero,
      child: child,
             );
            },
        ),
```

Comment: Either use  `animation: ReverseAnimation(_controller)` or set initial value to `1` when initializing `_controller`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Button Triggered Animation

#### 1. Setup Animation within initState

differs from many tutorial around, I suggest to put new function named setupAnimation which covers initial setup relates to animation

this is the first code structure we will have :

```dart
class BuilderAuto extends StatefulWidget { // Mandatory : Stateful
  @override
  _BuilderAutoState createState() => _BuilderAutoState();
}

class _BuilderAutoState extends State<BuilderAuto>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin { // Mandatory : inherit this class

  static AnimationController controller; // create class properties

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setupAnimation(); // wrap our initialization here
  }

  void setupAnimation() {
    // We initialize how many seconds will `some value` changes
    // and put it on some AnimationController which we may
    // control later, whether to increase `the value`, or decrease
    // `the value`

    controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
      vsync: this,
    );

    controller.forward();
  }
```

#### 2. Create some 'value' which ranges from some beginning Value to some ending Value

*later we will have this line of code*

```dart
final animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1)
```

**What does this mean ?**

- we will have some 'value' called animation.
- this value may changes *down to 0*
- this value may changes *up to 1*
- if this value increases, it will increase linearly
- if this value decreases, it will decrease linearly

**Why does it matter ?**

We will use this value, as a **reference** for our **moving object animation**

To move *an object* for 2 secs, we can have simple scenario like this :

- Initially, it is on x : 0, and y: 0 coordinate
- after 1s, it is on x : 50, and y : 30 coordinate
- Finally, it is on x : 100, and y : 60 coordinate

So, we can utilize **animation value** above which linearly changes.

#### 3. How to start changing some 'value' ?

*later we will extend this*

```dart
final animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1)
```

*to this*

```dart
final animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(controller)
```

**then to increase its value**

```dart
controller.forward();
```

**then to decrease its value**

```dart
controller.reverse();
```

#### 4. Why we need to use controller ?

because, simply in this very part, we define its Duration. So some 'value'
will understand how much time it takes to maximize and minimize its value.

```dart
controller = AnimationController(
  duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
  vsync: this,
);
```

#### 5. What to modify from original code ?

for your code :

**we need to change this build method**

```dart
AnimatedBuilder(
  animation: _controller,
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      DragObject(image: 'image/w1.png',position: post1,dataName: 't1',dataColor: Colors.blue,textField:null),
    ],
  ),
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child){
    return Transform.translate(
      offset: Offset.zero, // this should be modified time-by-time.
      child: child,
    );
  },
),
```

**to this build method**

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(controller);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Button Triggered'),
      ),
      body: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: animation,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            DragObject(image: 'image/w1.png',position: post1,dataName: 't1',dataColor: Colors.blue,textField:null),
          ],
        ),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          final xPos = 100 * animation.value;
          final yPos = 60 * animation.value;
          return Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(xPos, yPos),
            child: child,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

#### 6. For Full Working-example

You can look at [this repo](https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_tricky_layout/blob/master/lib/d_screen/builder_manual.dart)

[image: Demo]

Comment: Thank you very much it's working .. Is there a way to make it back to a specific point no matter where the widget because it is a function of the drag and drop and the possibility that the image anywhere on the screen

Comment: maybe we can try controller.reverse() as I suggested in  point #3

Comment: best animation explanation ever.. you are genius thank you